# A $\sigma$-algebra if A is algebra

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a set. 
Let $A \subset P(X)$ be a monotone class. Why is $A$ a $\sigma$-algebra iff $A$ is an algebra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any $\sigma$-algebra is an algebra, so that direction holds regardless of whether $\mathcal{A}$ is a monotone class.

Now assume $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra and a monotone class.
The ony thing new to check to see that $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra is the countable union property, so let $B_n, n \in \Bbb N$, be elements of $\mathcal{A}$, and $B=\cup_{n \in \Bbb N} B_n$.
Define $C_n = \cup_{i \le n} B_n \in \mathcal{A}$ as finite unions of elements of $\mathcal{A}$ (as $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra). Also $C_n \uparrow \cup_n C_n= B$, so the monotone class property tells us that $B \in \mathcal{A}$ as well, and we're done.